# Compare boolean Series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I need some help.

I have a dataframe with a int column. I want to test this values.

```
test1 = (data['CC'].shift(1) > 50) & (data['CC'] < 50)
test2 = (data['CC'].shift(1) < -50) & (data['CC'] > -50)
```

This code works and return a Series of 2000 rows. I have no problem with this.

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: CCI, dtype: bool
```

I want to use this Series to add a new column.

```
if(test1):
    data['Sloop'] = '+S'
elif(test2):
    data['Sloop'] = '-S'
else:
    data['Sloop'] = 'N'
```

The if statement is not working:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Of course, the test1 and test2 exists here. The real code is:

```
if((data['CC'].shift(1) > 50) & (data['CC'] < 50)):
    data['Sloop'] = '+S'
elif((data['CC'].shift(1) < -50) & (data['CC'] > -50)):
    data['Sloop'] = '-S'
else:
    data['Sloop'] = 'N'
```

Same error. Please, some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
test1 = (data['CC'].shift(1) > 50) & (data['CC'] < 50)
test2 = (data['CC'].shift(1) < -50) & (data['CC'] > -50)

data['Sloop'] = np.select([test1, test2], ['+S','-S'], default='N')
```